# How to write a numpy array to file in C++?

Tags: c++, numpy

I want to save a 5-Dim vector to .npy file in c++. I have already transform it to PyArrayObject:

```
PyArrayObject* numpyArray1 = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(5, Dims1, NPY_FLOAT, t1.data());
```

How can i save it to a .npy file?

Comment: I find a function PyArray_ToFile but when i use PyArray_ToFile(numpyArray1, filename,"","");  it crush and i do not know why.

Comment: The second argument is a `FILE*` not a filename

Comment: it is a FILE*  but still crush